# Auto rename Photos taken on iPhone to include datetime stamp

Tags: iphone, photos.app

I am looking for an easy way to export my photos taken on an iPhone 12 Pro Max that includes the date in the file name.

I am a long time Android user and Android phones typically follow variations of the following naming convention: YYYYMMDD-SomeRandomDigitSequence.

This is great for me because of some workflows that I have when working with images (ex: being able to quickly organize the files based on month/year and have them in the order they were taken within said folder). The biggest time this is an issue is when my wife is trying to make photo books and is uploading mass amounts of pictures to Shutterfly. The pictures get jumbled up because the file names do not have any discernible naming convention to keep them in order.

Anyways, is there any good way to do this? I am surprised that there are no options for changing the name that photos are stored once taken, and doubly surprised that there aren't any export options that will read the exif data to accomplish this built into Photos.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Digital photographs by all convention are sequentially numbered. Though this doesn't show the date, it's equivalent to 'order taken'. Once on the Mac, you can easily sort a folder by date. I'm not seeing where the real issue lies. I suppose it would be possible to prepend the dates, but for something like that I'd be inclined to use something like 'A Better Finder Rename' - eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wDEu.png

Comment: I'll check out A Better Finder Rename. As far "Seeing the real issue", I think I explained the issue clearly enough. The convenience of having the device name the photos with the date taken PLUS sequence would be preferable for the workflows we have. Since that isn't an option on iPhone I was looking for an easier way to export or rename those files. Hopefully the app you provided fits the bill.